# Blend single element within a fixed/sticky container with the body

Tags: html, css, mix-blend-mode

In my project, I have a top bar with `position: fixed` that consists of a small layout of a logo and some other items.
What I'm trying to achieve is to apply a `mix-blend-mode: multiply` to the logo only, such that it blends with the body. But:

- The other items should not get the blend effect and should just be rendered black
- The Logo and the other items should stay in a container (with `display: flex`) together, so that I can control their layout.

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, lime, deeppink, lime);
  height: 200vh;
}

.top-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;

  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.item {
  /* How can I escape from mix-blend mode here and just render this black? */
}
```

```html
<div class="top-bar">  
  <div class="logo">
    LOGO
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    item-1
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    item-2
  </div>
</div>
```

What I tried:

- Apply `mix-blend-mode: multiply` to `.logo`. But then it will blend with it's container (`.top-bar`) and not with `body`. (Resulting in no effect)
- Try to use `isolation: isolate`, but I'm not sure if this is the right approach here.
- Try to get rid of the wrapper div (`.top-bar`) and make `.logo` and the `.item`-elements direct children of body. But then I lose the ability to layout those elements correctly in a flexbox.

Comment: basically not possible if you cannot remove position: fixed or place the items outside the container